# Hide multiple sheets based on a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good Afternoon,

I am fairly new to scripts for Google Sheets (getting used to Excel differences) and am trying to hide multiple sheets ("Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3"... all the way to week 9) and only show one based on a cell (j10 in a sheet "Control Panel").  If j10 has a "4", only "Week 4" will show.

I see a way to do this one sheet at a time [based on this old Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812657/google-spreadsheets-hide-sheets-based-on-cell-value) using 9 "if statements" and each statement having 9 commands to either hide all but one "Week" sheet. Basically, I'm looking to considerably simplify that code to not be so slow.

So I tried to use some script from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111853/how-do-i-hide-a-sheet?newreg=c9cbb580bfb746f3890476b9527f6c6c) that was written before the hidesheet() method existed by looping a command, but I'm having trouble.

Thank you for considering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you don't want to hide the sheet 'Control Panel' ? Try below script

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getName() == 'Control Panel' && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'J10' && e.value > 0 && e.value < 10) {
    e.source.getSheets()
        .forEach(function (sh) {
            (sh.getName() !== 'Week ' + e.value && sh.getName() !== 'Control Panel') ? sh.hideSheet() : sh.showSheet();
        })
}
}
```

NOTE: this script uses a simple onEdit trigger. So don't try to run it from the script editor (by clicking the 'play' button). Instead, go to sheet 'Control Panel' and enter a value (> 0 and  < 9) in J10.

Comment: Thank you, JPV for the help.. it works perfectly. The onEdit works perfect for this document. If I have another document, that I want a timed trigger, would it be similar code? I would like to use this in a case where J10 in "Control Panel" is calculated by a formula using the =WeekDay or =Now function and then weekly it checks what J10 has to open the correct tab.

Comment: @AaronSmith: if it works, then please accept my answer. :-) If you need a script on a clock trigger, the code will be slightly different (as there would not be an event object, e). function checkJ10() { var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('name_of_tab').getRange('j10') var value =  cell.getValue()... .then check if value is the desired value and act upon that...