# Can we hide sheets according to the content page row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to hide the sheets according to the register row?  I can get it done in excel sheet not sure if google sheet can do so.

I have a register showing the list of activities and the location. Each activity shown on the register is link to a google sheet and the sheets name is according to cell B4:B. The register will show the relevant row according to the drop down list in cell G2. onEdit(e) function already created to hide row when there is a change in the drop down list.

Sample of register: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prBzJ.jpg)   Picture tab name: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLJjj.jpg)

If the drop down list is change to hub 01 [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIJbm.png), only the relevant sheets will be shown,  irrelevant sheets will remain hidden.

The first 5 sheets must be shown at all time. I try to follow the example [Hide Sheets Based on a Cell Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393622/hide-sheets-based-on-a-cell-value/52409797#52409797) and create a function to hide the sheet. But it hide every sheets.

```
 function HideSheet()
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheets = ss.getSheets();

for ( var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) 
{
var name = sheets[i].getName();
if (name != "Site Location" ,"Risk Register", "RM team member", "Risk Matrix", "Register History")
{ 
var value = ss.getSheetByName('Risk Register').getRange('B4:B').getValue();
if (name.match(new RegExp(value, 'gi')))
sheets[i].showSheet();
else
sheets[i].hideSheet();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to show the sheets with the sheet names retrieving from the column "B4:B".

  - The rows are shown by the basic filter. You want to hide sheets with the sheet names of rows hidden by the basic filter.
  - You always want to show the sheets of "Site Location" ,"Risk Register", "RM team member", "Risk Matrix", "Register History"`.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In your script,

  - `if (name != "Site Location" ,"Risk Register", "RM team member", "Risk Matrix", "Register History")` is not correct. In this case, it is requried to be `if (name != "Site Location" && name != "Risk Register" ,,,`.
  - `var value = ss.getSheetByName('Risk Register').getRange('B4:B').getValue()` is the value of "B4".
  - The filtered rows cannot be checked. So all values are always used.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows. The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Create object for searching the shown sheet names.
2. Create object for searching the current sheets.
3. Retrieve values from the column "B".
4. Hide or show the sheets using the created objects by checking the filtered row.

#### Modified script:

```
function HideSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // 1. Create object for searching the shown sheet names.
  var shownSheetNames = ["Site Location" ,"Risk Register", "RM team member", "Risk Matrix", "Register History"];
  var obj = shownSheetNames.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e]: true}), {});

  // 2. Create object for searching the current sheets.
  var sheetsObj = ss.getSheets().reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e.getSheetName().toLowerCase()]: e}), {});

  // 3. Retrieve values from the column "B".
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Risk register");
  var values = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 4. Hide or show the sheets using the created objects by checking the filtered row.
  for (var r = 4; r <= sheet.getLastRow(); r++) {
    var sheetName = values[r - 1][0].toLowerCase();
    if (sheetName && sheetsObj[sheetName]) {  // <--- Modified
      if (sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(r)) {
        if (!obj[sheetName]) sheetsObj[sheetName].hideSheet();
      } else {
        sheetsObj[sheetName].showSheet();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- In this modification, you can also use this script by putting `HideSheet()` to the function of `onEdit` as your question saying.

#### References:

- [isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: much appreciate for your help again. however, i encounter error as shown. [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/uubI79w.jpg) anything after sheetsObj the var cannot be read.

Comment: @Sherry Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From the error message, I thought that the values of column "B" might include the not existing sheet names in the Spreadsheet. So for this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong, the var sheetsObj cannot call the function SheetName? if i remove the getSheetName().toLowerCase().  then i won't have such error. (var SheetName font color will turn blue). However, if i add back getSheetName().toLowerCase(), the error will return. (var SheetName font color will be black)

Comment: @Sherry Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. At `sheetsObj`, an object is created as the key of the sheet name. For this, `e.getSheetName()` is used. About `toLowerCase()`, in your script, `i` is used in the regex. So the sheet name is used for being able to use both uppercase and lowercase. If you want to remove `toLowerCase()`, please remove it for both `e.getSheetName().toLowerCase()` and `values[r - 1][0].toLowerCase()`.

Comment: @Sherry When `.getSheetName().toLowerCase()` is removed, `sheetsObj` cannot be used for searching the existing sheets. In this case, no error occurs at the if statement, because the script in the if statement is not run. So the sheets are not hidden and shown.

Comment: i understand what you mean if i remove the .getSheetName().  i placed the var sheetsObj after the for (var r = 4 ......) and it works well. Thanks for your help on this!
      for (var r = 4; r <= sheet.getLastRow(); r++) {
      var sheetsObj = ss.getSheets().reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, 
    {[e.getSheetName().toLowerCase()]: e}), {});

Comment: @Sherry Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.